# Multiplication between two TextBox values in SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]

How to Multiply [HowManyTrucks] and TextBox11 values and store it in TextBox33.

[HowManyTrucks] is a field from Dataset.
TextBox11 is a value calculated by subtracting [BasePrice] and [DiscountValue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do exactly what you are requesting, use the following formula in TextBox33:
    =SUM(Fields!HowManyTrucks.Value) * ReportItems!TextBox11.Value

That being said, I would urge you to actually move both the values in TextBox11 and TextBox33 into your dataset as calculated columns.

```
SELECT
HowManyTrucks
,BasePrice
,DiscountValue
,BasePrice - DiscountValue AS PerTruckDiscountedPrice
,(BasePrice - DiscountValue) * HowManyTrucks AS TotalDiscountedPrice
FROM OrderTable
```

Managing SSRS reports in the long term gets more difficult as you start adding in formulas to cells. With this method, if you need to change the logic for these cells, you can do it in the dataset and it will cascade to other parts of the report where this logic might be used.

Comment: also, I want to repeat value of Textbox33 into another texbox. I get this error: 'report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope'

Comment: this wouldnt happen if you moved the values to calculated columns in your dataset because you'd be able to reference the dataset rather than the report item.

Comment: Deven, how many datasets are in this report? I had assumed just one, but now I'm thinking I might have been wrong. You should not get an out of scope error unless the two text boxes have different datasets.